# Mongo node expressJs database connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using a `mongoDB` database with `node` / `express` and I want to know how could I make this more concise.

```
    app.get('/mediums', function(req, res){
        db.open(function(err, db) {
            db.collection('mediums').find().toArray(function(err, info){
                res.json(info)
                db.close();
            })
        });
    });
    app.get('/categories', function(req, res){
        db.open(function(err, db) {
            db.collection('categories').find().toArray(function(err, info){
                res.json(info)
                db.close();
            })
        });
    });
    app.get('/stock', function(req, res){
        db.open(function(err, db) {
            db.collection('stock').find().toArray(function(err, info){
                res.json(info)
                db.close();
            })
        });
    });
```

I want to write the `db.open` one time and then call it when I need it
something more like

```
database = db.open(function(err, db) {
    db.collection('stock').find().toArray(function(err, info){
        callback()
        db.close();
    })
});


app.get('/stock', function(req, res){
    database.collection('stocks').find().toArray(function(err, info ){
      res.json(info)
    })
});
```

I know this is not valid JS but something like this would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the `mongoDB` connection is kept open forever when the server is run. It is inefficient and cumbersome to open and close the connection every time. Just open the connection when you start the server and pass that variable wherever you need to query the database.

You can do something like this

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
   //start your express server here
   //use the db to query in the routes.
   //If you need the db in other files, you can use something like exports.db=db
   //in the case db isn't a singleton.

})
```

Comment: Thanks thats good to know. I'm new to the whole backend thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your app initialization stuff inside the callback from `db.open`. Something like this:

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
    app.get('/mediums', function(req, res){
        db.collection('mediums').find().toArray(function(err, info){
            res.json(info);
        });
    });
    app.get('/categories', function(req, res){
        db.collection('categories').find().toArray(function(err, info){
            res.json(info);
        });
    });
    app.get('/stock', function(req, res){
        db.collection('stock').find().toArray(function(err, info){
            res.json(info);
        });
    });
});
```

You'll probably want your `.listen` call inside the `db.open` callback as well so that the app doesn't start listening before the db connection is open.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

**app.js / server.js**

```
...    
let _db = null;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', (err, db) => {
    _db = db;
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.db = _db;
    next();
});
...
```

**routes/mediums.js**

```
...
router.get('/mediums', function(req, res) {
    res.locals.db.collection('mediums').find().toArray(function(err, info){
        res.json(info)
        db.close();
    });
});
...
```